# A proof that $L^{\infty}$ is complete

Tags: probability-theory, banach-spaces, solution-verification, cauchy-sequences

I know this has been proved in other links, but I am wondering about the validity of the following proof:

Suppose $X_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $L^\infty$.  Then there exists a subsequence $Y_k \equiv X_{n_k}$ such that $\|Y_{k+1} - Y_k \|_\infty < \frac{1}{2^k}$.

Define $H_n \equiv \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}|Y_{k+1} - Y_k|$ and note that $\|H_n\|_\infty \leq \sum_{k=0}^\infty \|Y_{k+1} - Y_k\|_\infty \leq 2$ so that $H \equiv \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} H_n$ is well defined and finite almost surely (so $H_n$ is Cauchy in $\mathbb{R}$ almost surely).  Thus $Y_k$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ since (WLOG put $m \ge n$)

$$|Y_m - Y_n| \leq H_m - H_n < \epsilon \quad \text{ for } m, n \text{ large}$$

and thus $Y_k$ is convergent to a limit, say $X$.  To see that this is the $L^\infty$ limit for the subsequence, we note that $$\|Y_n - X\|_\infty \leq \|H- H_n\|_\infty \leq \sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac{1}{2^k} \xrightarrow{n \rightarrow \infty} 0$$

Now we note that there exists $N$ such that $m,n \ge N$ implies $\|X_m - X_n\|_\infty < \epsilon/2$ and such that $k \ge N$ implies $\|Y_k - X\|_\infty < \epsilon/2$  Thus for $n \ge N$, we obtain (choosing any $k \ge N$ and noting $n_k \ge k$),

$$\|X_n - X \|_\infty \leq \|X_n - X_{n_k} \|_\infty + \|X_{n_k} - X\|_\infty < \epsilon$$

and we are done.  Does this work?  Any feedback is much appreciated!

Comment: I don't think this works per se, $Y_k$ is not a sequence of numbers in $\mathbb R$, but a sequence in $L^\infty$. The same goes for the *functions* $H_k$, which don't do anything: we already know that every representative $y_k$ of $Y_k$ is essentially bounded (i.e. finite almost surely), just from the fact that a Cauchy sequence in a normed space (complete or not) must be bounded.

Comment: Yes $Y_k$ is a sequence in $L^\infty$, but when I write $|Y_n - Y_m|$ I am abusing notation.  I actually mean $|Y_n(\omega) - Y_m(\omega)|$, and the sequence of real numbers $Y_n(\omega)$ is what I am dealing with.  I am trying to construct a pointwise limit on the set where $H < \infty$, which is an almost sure set.  Do you still think it doesn't work, with this clarification? I think it does

Comment: Sorry, I have no time at the moment to read carefully

Comment: Sure no worries.