# Does $L^\infty$ convergence imply convergence almost surely?

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, uniform-convergence

I'm not quite sure if the following proof is correct.  Suppose we are working on the measure space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ and let $X$ denote the $L^{\infty}$ limit

Let $A = \{\omega \in \Omega: |X_n(\omega) - X(\omega)| \leq \|X_n - X\|_\infty \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}\}$

$A$ occurs almost surely since it is the intersection of countably many almost sure sets.  Fix $\epsilon > 0 $ and $N$ such that $n \ge N$ implies $\| X_n - X\|_\infty < \epsilon $. Now for $\omega \in A$, we have for all $n \ge N$, $$|X_n(\omega) - X(\omega)| \leq \|X_n - X\|_\infty < \epsilon$$

so that $X_n(\omega) \rightarrow X(\omega)$ almost surely and, in fact, the convergence is uniform on $A$, i.e. almost sure convergence uniformly.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your proof is correct.  There aren't any other subtleties.

Comment: Thanks! I am also interested in verifying another proof concerning $L^\infty$, if you have the time to take a look: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3703236/a-proof-that-l-infty-is-complete?noredirect=1#comment7610753_3703236